# What is OL3 equivalent of numberOfTiers in openlayers 2

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I was calculating custom zoom level based on `numberOfTiers` in `Openlayers` 2.

How could I get this parameter in `OL3`?

Also, how could I get zoom level based on Resolution?

```
z = this.getZoomForResolution(res)
```

z calculation in `OL3` would be really appreciated.